# is there a proper way to make a responsive design using vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js, responsive

since I am new in designing, in tailwindcss there are classes like XS, SM, MD, LG, XL etc. these classes are very useful for making the design response.
but is there a proper way to make a responsive web in VURTIFY,
I have read VURTIFY dos,
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/spacing/

it defines some break points too, but can't understand it uses, please provide a proper resource or information about how I do use VURTIFY for responsive design instead of it grid system.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuetify has a complete class list for responsive design. According to [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/display/#visibility), You can use classes like `d-{breakpoint}-{value}` to set display on different breakpoints, for example, You can use `d-lg-none` class to set `display: none` for an element only on large devices or use `d-sm-flex` class to set `display: flex` only on small devices.

You can also use `hidden-{breakpoint}-{condition}` to hide an element in some displays, for example, You can use `hidden-xs-only` to hide an element on very small devices or use `hidden-md-and-up` to hide an element on medium devices or larger.

Furthermore, You can use the [`Breakpoint service object`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/#breakpoint-service-object) in javascript, for example, you can show an element only on small devices and etc.

```html
<h1 v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smOnly">
   Hello world!
</h1>
```